# How to use nested case when in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query, that needs little tweaks. I've edited my question. 
I have a column in **Data_table** called **FileID**

This Column FileID has incremental numbers from 1 to goes on. So the below script works exactly fine for the **FileID <= 54**. But for FileID > 55, I wanted to change my below code to use '**DataDescription2**' instead of 1.

```
        with data as ( SELECT  A.[WalkAwayFileID],
                A.[SubmissionNumber],       -- check DD1/DD2
                A.[MasterPolicyNumber],
                MAX(CASE when  DataDescription1 = 'Total Bound Premium ($)' then ivalue else NULL end) as WalkawayBoundPremium,
                MAX(CASE when  DataDescription1 = 'Underwriter Adjusted Benchmark Premium ($) for Layer Bound' then iValue else NULL end) as UAB_Premium, 
                MAX(case when DataDescription1 = 'Currency' then svalue else NULL end ) as Currency


        FROM Tool_Record A 
        JOIN Data_table B ON A.[WalkAwayFileID] = B.FileID 

        group by a.WalkAwayFileID, a.SubmissionNumber, a.MasterPolicyNumber
        ) 

        select   *From data
```

Here is the below underlying table where I have highlighted how the data is captured.

[image]

Comment: The format of your question makes it hard to follow.  Can you show us sample input data along with the expected output (as text, in your question) ?

Comment: Hi Tim, I modified the question above

Answer (score 0):

Can you not simply add logic to handle this:

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT
        A.[WalkAwayFileID],
        A.[SubmissionNumber],
        A.[MasterPolicyNumber],
        MAX(CASE WHEN FileID <= 54 AND DataDescription1 = 'Total Bound Premium ($)'
            OR
                FileID > 54 AND DataDescription2 = 'Total Bound Premium ($)'
                 THEN ivalue ELSE NULL END) AS WalkawayBoundPremium,
        MAX(CASE WHEN FileID <= 54 AND
            DataDescription1 = 'Underwriter Adjusted Benchmark Premium ($) for Layer Bound'
            OR
                FileID > 54 AND
            DataDescription2 = 'Underwriter Adjusted Benchmark Premium ($) for Layer Bound'
                 THEN iValue ELSE NULL END) AS UAB_Premium, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN FileID <= 54 AND DataDescription1 = 'Currency' OR
                      FileID > 54 AND DataDesription2 = 'Currency'
                 THEN svalue ELSE NULL END) AS Currency
    FROM Tool_Record A 
    INNER JOIN Data_table B
        ON A.[WalkAwayFileID] = B.FileID 
    GROUP BY
        a.WalkAwayFileID, a.SubmissionNumber, a.MasterPolicyNumber
 )
```